# How to check Google Mobile Services enable in device or not?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, google-play-services, huawei-mobile-services

I have to check if google services are active on the device. How can I check it? Looking just play services is enough?

I need this check for Huawei services.

Comment: Please look at this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60587678/619673

Answer (score 2):

```
final int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        Log.e(TAG, GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorString(status));
                  return false;
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorString(status));
                   return true;
    }
```

Comment: yes ; I think it is enough for checking location services and push services in google?

Answer (score 2):

You should use `GoogleApiAvailability` API. `GooglePlayServicesUtil` API is deprecated, don't use it.

Java:

```
public boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(final Context context) {
    return GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(context) == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS;
}
```

Kotlin:

```
fun Context.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(): Boolean =
    GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this) == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this code will help you

```
final int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        Log.e(TAG, GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorString(status));
                  return false;
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorString(status));
                   return true;
    }
```

.

```
public static final int SUCCESS = 0;
public static final int SERVICE_MISSING = 1;
public static final int SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED = 2;
public static final int SERVICE_DISABLED = 3;
public static final int SIGN_IN_REQUIRED = 4;
public static final int INVALID_ACCOUNT = 5;
public static final int RESOLUTION_REQUIRED = 6;
public static final int NETWORK_ERROR = 7;
public static final int INTERNAL_ERROR = 8;
public static final int SERVICE_INVALID = 9;
public static final int DEVELOPER_ERROR = 10;
public static final int LICENSE_CHECK_FAILED = 11;
public static final int CANCELED = 13;
public static final int TIMEOUT = 14;
public static final int INTERRUPTED = 15;
public static final int API_UNAVAILABLE = 16;
public static final int SIGN_IN_FAILED = 17;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use these codes to check:

```
boolean flag = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this) == com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult.SUCCESS
```

If `flag == true`, then GMS is enable in device.

If `flag == false`, then GMS is disable in device.

Comment: What is `this`?

Comment: @m0skit0 `this` is Context varl.

Answer (score 1):

The latest solution for 2022 is **GoogleApiAvailabilityLight** from package **com.google.android.gms.common** which is contained in dependency

> com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:18.0.0@aar

```
public static boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(final Context context) {
  return GoogleApiAvailabilityLight.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(context) == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS;
```

}