# HMS Huawei management service

Tags: firebase, xamarin.forms, release, huawei-mobile-services, appgallery

I have published a new app, I don't use any of Google services such as Google Maps, Push notifications, Authentication or etc, the app functionality is simple and depends on our own business data.

I used Huawei Y9 EMUI version 9.1.0, and 10.0.0, I found the app on Huawei AppGallery, and I installed it successfully and it worked perfectly.

But I used Huawei Y9a EMUI version 10.1.1, also EMUI version 11.0.0, the app does not appear on Huawei AppGallery, and if I open it by the browser the install button will be disabled.

So, I have installed the package manually as a (`.apk`) file, it worked perfectly so there are no compatibility issues, but the app still does not appear on Huawei AppGallery for these versions.

After communicating with Huawei Customer Service, they just told me the following:

> Your app depends on GMS services, so it is only available on HUAWEI
> GMS devices. I suggest you integrate our HMS services into the app to
> make it be available on all of HUAWEI devices(including HUAWEI HMS
> devices). https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/hms.

So, the point here is how I can make this integration (The link they send is for Huawei Mobile Services in general).

So, what should I do to make my app appear on Huawei Mobile Services? or how to integrate this service on Huawei AppGallery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I communicated with [Huawei support team](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/support/feedback/#/ticketlist), since i'm not using any of GMS services, they reviewed the package and then they published it on app gallery.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you don't understand how App Gallery works. App Gallery is the system that works almost identically like Google Play. Among other things it means that you need to build app signed with specific signatures approved by Huawei and submit the app to App Gallery which you obviously haven't done. You need to replace any Google Play package that you may use with the HMS package and change your code according to that.

But that is far from all. It will take days or even months if you want to publish in China market and especially if it is a game. You need to pay fees to Chinese authorities, submit some documents and receive some certifications from them. Among other things you may need to hand over complete code of your app to the Chinese government if it is not a big app to receive the copyright that is necessary for App Gallery in China.

Comment: thanks Ivan for reply. this is the first time I published on Huawei App Gallery, and i don't use any of google packages till the moment, and the application is distribute it on only one country (Jordan). i have already made Key Store and signed my package when i published it on google play. should i made other sign? do i need to write any code or use some files? is there any guideline straight forward to publish it?

Comment: @FSD App Gallery Connect is similar to what Google Play Console is, you should open account there and you will find support documents there: https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/service/josp/agc/index.html#/

Answer (score 1):

> what should I do to make my app appear on HMS? or how to integrate this service on Huawei app gallery?

First, you need to select a proper solution (**G+H** or **G2H**) based on the application scenario and development/test costs.

1. If you choose G+H solution, you need to check whether the GMS is available. If the GMS interface cannot be used properly, HMS is required.
2. If you choose G2H solution, the workload of compatibility test is small. You only need to test the new APK on Huawei phones. Release your app both on HUAWEI AppGallery and Google Play, with different packages. The app you release on AppGallery contains only Huawei's logic code.
3. You can also use [HMS Toolkit Convertor](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/Tools-Guides/convertor-0000001050147221?ha_source=hms1). It supports G+H and G2H conversion. Currently, HMS Toolkit supports Java and Kotlin.

For details, You may refer to this question: [Have both GMS and HMS in the project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59974428/13329100).

Huawei has also provided some HMS Core kit plugins for React Native, Cordova and Xamarin. [Reference documents](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/rn-intro-0000001050975015)