# Facebook Audience Network ads are not working when the app is downloaded from Huawei AppGallery

Tags: android, ads, huawei-mobile-services, facebook-audience-network, huawei-ads

I have an Android app that has been published on Play Store & I integrated Facebook Audience Network (FAN) ads into it. Since most of the new Huawei devices don't have Play Store, I published the same app to Huawei AppGallery.

The problem is FAN ads are not showing when the app is downloaded from the AppGallery. But the same ads are working fine when downloaded from the Play Store. Can anyone help me to solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Facebook Audience Network Only Supports Apps that are Published on Google PlayStore and Apple App Store. If your app is downloaded outside of the play store and app store your app won't Facebook show ads. You can Check that [here](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/1195459597167215?id=211412110064838#:~:text=before%20you%20begin)

If you have traffic from outside other than the above-mentioned stores, you have to request the Facebook team to Enable ads for outside traffic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Huawei AppGallery, You may use [Huawei Ads kit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/hms/huawei-adskit?ha_source=hms1) in your app.

HUAWEI Ads Publisher Service is a monetization service that leverages Huawei's extensive data capabilities to display high-quality ad content in your apps to the vast user base of Huawei devices.

For more details, pls kindly check [Docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/publisher-service-introduction-0000001070671805).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But If I use Huawei ads I have to maintain 2 versions of my app, one for Play Store & another for AppGallery. Currently I'm publishing the same app (.aab file) to the both stores. And I've seen Google admob works fine for both Play Store &  AppGallery apps. Is it possible to do the same with FAN ads?

Comment: If I use Huawei ads I have to maintain 2 versions of my app, one for Play Store & another for AppGallery. ---you may choose G+H solution, kindly check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59974428/13329100).

Comment: According to the team, Currently, FAN ads are not supported.Whether it will be supported in the future is unknown.Therefore, You are advised to preferentially use Huawei Ads on your Huawei phone.