# Does using HMS push notifications work on Meizu, Oppo, Xiaomi and Vivo?

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-play-services, huawei-mobile-services, baidu

I'm working on push notification for an app and I've come across FCM (Firebase Could Messaging), HMS (Huawei Mobile Services) Push Kit and Baidu Cloud Push. I also noticed Meizu, Oppo, Xiaomi and Vivo provide their own push notification service.

I can see Baidu allows you to proxy to Huawei, Meizu, Oppo, Xiaomi and Vivo and possibly supports Samsung and other androids by default (does it?). However, I am unable to create an account even using a Chinese mobile number. I'll probably need to VPN to a Chinese network to for this.

Actual Question:
I'm looking at G+H solution as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64782622/1378980). HMS Push Kit looks like god-send, but does it work on Meizu, Oppo, Xiaomi and Vivo? If it doesn't, would G+B (B for Baidu) be the easiest approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acorrding to [this Docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/service-introduction-0000001050040060#section4559183416556) , Huawei Push Kit supports the following devices:

[image]

But on other phones except Huawei devices, because push kit strongly depends on the HMS Core, And it does not have keepalive on other phones. so it may be killed by processes.

Comment: In that case, I might use Baidu Cloud until other devices accept Huawei's invitation to unify the services and use HMS on their devices. Baidu actually just proxies to HMS for push notifications on Huawei devices anyway.