# Migration an app(maps,analystics..etc.) from google play to Huawei App Gallery

Tags: google-maps, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, huawei-push-notification, huawei-map-kit

I have an app on the Google Play Market and I developed that with Google Play services, maps, analytics, location services. now I need to migrate this app to the Huawei app gallery, I need to publish the app with the same features on the Huawei App Gallery too,How can I migrate? especially how can I migrate the google map for Huawei services? Need I change the codes, need I remove the google maps to migrate the app ? could you share your experiences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your app to run on Huawei phones, integrate [Huawei Mobile Services (HMS)](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/hms).

If you want to use the map service in your app, and also want your app to run on both Huawei phones and Google Android phones, you can integrate both GMS Map Kit and HMS Map Kit. Then your app will use HMS Map Kit on Huawei phones, while using GMS Map Kit on Google Android phones.

In the list you provided, you use these GMS services:

> maps, analytics, location services.

You can refer to the following Huawei mobile services:

[Map kit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/hms/huawei-MapKit) , [Analytics kit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/hms/huawei-analyticskit) , [Location kit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/hms/huawei-locationkit).

You can use this IDE plug-in called [HMS Core Toolkit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/huawei-toolkit/) to help you analyze where GMS is used in your code. HMS Core Toolkit supports analysis of manual conversion, aiming to increase the conversion efficiency. It provides two conversion policies: Add HMS API and To HMS API. You can choose one as required.

For more details about conversion, you could aslo refer to this questions: [Have both GMS and HMS in the project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59974428/13329100).