# Check the Huawei Mobile Services (HMS) availability

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services

How I can detect that HMS services are available for some phone?

The question is a duplicate of [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60587678/6580079) but let it be cause googling with `check huawei services is available` didn't provide me with a link for StackOverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59974428/have-both-gms-and-hms-in-the-project/60587678#60587678) (Have both GMS and HMS in the project). Let Google indexing this for better search possibilities.

Answer (score 5):

First of all you should read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60587678/6580079).
The answer contains the link to the old documentation version of HMS. Here is the new one - [link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/hmscore-common-References/huaweiapiavailability-0000001050121134). Find the `isHuaweiMobileServicesAvailable` method and read about return constants description.

Best wishes!

Answer (score 5):

You can use this method to detect

```
public static boolean isHmsAvailable(Context context) {
        boolean isAvailable = false;
        if (null != context) {
            int result = HuaweiApiAvailability.getInstance().isHuaweiMobileServicesAvailable(context);
            isAvailable = (com.huawei.hms.api.ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == result);
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "isHmsAvailable: " + isAvailable);
        return isAvailable;
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, I know, thanks)