# Add keywords to huawei app in huawei develoer console

Tags: ios, app-store, huawei-mobile-services, keyword-search, appgallery-connect

I need to provide users with ability to search for my app in huawei app gallery like Apple's Keywords in app store , but i can't find the equivalent to it in huawei developer console

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Huawei provide many ad types to help you increase the downloads of your Android apps. You can set words or phrases to match your ad with user search terms.

The procedure is as follows:

1. Go to **Tools > Asset management > App management**, add your app, and select the countries/regions where you want to promote the app.
2. Create a campaign.
   [image]
3. Create an ad task.
   [image]

   [image]

For details, please refer to [this docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/promotion/appgallery-search-0000001228034693).

Comment: Hi thanks for the help , but i can't get where is tools tab ?

Comment: Also can you please help with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72613819/get-lifetime-number-of-downloads-of-huawei-app

Comment: please i need to know where is menu tools please add screenshoots

Comment: hi@sheko, the access portal is on [this website](https://ads.huawei.com/usermgtportal/home/index.html#/), If you have any questions about ad access, you can [submit a ticket](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/support/feedback/#/), choose *HUAWEI ads* and the ad team will handle your questions.

Comment: Is it a paid service ?

Comment: Looks like it.@sheko, to use this function need to register an ad account. For details you could check [this docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/promotion/settlement-overview-0000001176952305).