# Get lifetime number of downloads of huawei app

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, appgallery-connect

I have an app on huawei's App gallery , i need to know the number of downloads since app uploaded , but every time i select a wide range it tells me period in between shouldn't exceed 180 days , and there is no lifetime item under last month like what it in apple store and google play

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Confirm with the team that the current AGC console only supports access to data of 180 days. You can filter data forward, but the data cannot exceed 180 days at a time. This will be described in the documents in the future.

Comment: appreciate the help  ,but please where is **Tools > Asset management** here  please i need to know where is menu tools please add screenshoots https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72591101/add-keywords-to-huawei-app-in-huawei-develoer-console to accept the answer

Comment: hi@sheko, I updated my response under that question, please check.